# Surefire : How to change output behaviour

Tags: java, maven-2, surefire

I'm looking in a way to only write txt files for unit tests that failed when using maven with surefire. The current behaviour of the surefire plugin is that it writes .txt and .xml file for every test it is running.

A bit like what the surefire-report plugin allows us to do with :

```
<configuration>
   <showSuccess>false</showSuccess>
</configuration>
```

Regards,

F

Comment: I take you have issues with .xml files, no the .txt files?  And because of that you only want Surefire to only write .txt files?

Comment: Actually, I found a way to get only .txt files. But now, among the txt, I'd like surefire to create txt only when a test failed. So instead of having 390 .txt files in the surefire folder, I'll have only the one of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Surefire can't do what you're looking for.  If the setting isn't available in the [mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html), you can't do it.

Another option would be to write a plugin that scrapes the report directory after the test phase (perhaps in prepare-package?) and deletes any passing tests.

Personally, I just sort the directory by file size when something fails.